# Convert multiline string to single line string

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and I need to put a multiline string in the datastore. Unfortunately, GAE does not allow that. I need this string to be multiline, so is there any way to convert a multiline string to a single line string and store it?

Comment: +1 for asking the ultimate problem instead of the proximate issue and expecting us all to guess (that happens too much 'round these parts ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need no conversion:

[google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty)(multiline=True)

Comment: Haha, turned out my string was too many kb anyway, so I made it a TextProperty.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all newlines with "\n", and replace all "\" with "\\", just like the way you do with string literals:

```
def encode(s):
    return s.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\n", "\\n")
def decode(s):
    return s.replace("\\\\", "\\").replace("\\n", "\n")
```

Comment: Do as I say, not as I code. There is a bug in the code, but the principle is sound.